# django views if statement not working with a boolean

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, if-statement, boolean

My if statment always goes to the Else even if the boolean value changes?
Working in Django 1.6.5

views.py

```
def awaiting_email_confirmation(request):
    confirmed = EmailConfirmed.objects.get(user=request.user)
    print confirmed
    if confirmed is False:
        print "if"
        template = 'accounts/email_confirmation.html'
        context = {}
        return render(request, template, context)   
    else:
        print "else"
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("dashboard"))
```

My console will print

```
True
else

False
else
```

This is my model.py for email confirmed

```
class EmailConfirmed(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.confirmed)
```

Comment: EmailConfirmed is a model instance. Does it perhaps have a boolean attribute you mean to test against? For example `confirmed.confirmed`?

Comment: Can you post your model code for `EmailConfirmed` class?

Comment: To debug try to replace the line `print confirmed` with `print confirmed, type(confirmed)` and the type should be bool not string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `print` statement shows `True` or `False` because you are returning the string representation of a boolean value in your `str` override. In other words, you are printing the strings 'True' or 'False'. The actual boolean field `confirmed` is a field in your model. You should change your if condition to:

```
if not confirmed.confirmed:
    ...
```

By the way, it may be a better idea to use `get_object_or_404` method instead of `get()` to return a 404 page instead of a server error when no `EmailConfirmed` objects could be found:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
...
def awaiting_email_confirmation(request):
    confirmed = get_object_or_404(EmailConfirmed, user=request.user)
    if not confirmed.confirmed:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I adapted the code from catavaran & Selcuk.

view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def awaiting_email_confirmation(request):
confirmed = get_object_or_404(EmailConfirmed, user=request.user)
if not confirmed.confirmed:
    template = 'accounts/email_confirmation.html'
    context = {}
    return render(request, template, context)
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("dashboard"))
```

This is now working with my test cases.